# Not able to push the items into an array after geting files from database

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I am getting the files from a collection called file_uploads from Database. At the same time, I am getting the directory files from another location and storing it in files_to_read []. looping through both the files I am matching the files and then push it to files_to_simulate array.

```
const fs = require('fs')
let folder = '../../importedFiles/data';
let files_to_read = []
let files = fs.readdirSync(folder);
let fileSchema = require('../db/models/fileUpload');
let files_to_simulate = [];

files.forEach(file => {
    let fileStat = fs.statSync(folder + '/' + file).isDirectory();
    if(!fileStat) {
        files_to_read.push(file);
    }
});

fileSchema.find({}, async function(err, files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        files_to_read.forEach(function(directoryFile) {
            var dbFile = file.name.split('.');
            let dirFile = directoryFile.split('.');
            if (dbFile[0] === dirFile[0]) {
                console.log('saa')
                files_to_simulate.push(dirFile[0]);
            }
        })
    })
});

console.log(files_to_simulate)
```

Comment: It works fine but the console.log doesn't log the response because of the callback of fileSchema is an asynchronous function

Comment: ya, that's the issue I want the dirfile[0] to store in the files_to_simulate array.
So I used console.log(files_to_simulate) to see whether it is storing in the array or not. But, unfortunately it isn't getting stored. could you please help me out with this.

Comment: As I said the console.log executed synchronously but your callback function executed asynchronously. so you are not able to see the result but code works fine and files_to_simulate array fill with result asynchronously.Here you can find about asynchronous in javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am running out of time. Could be more specific for this code to work in asynchronous way?

Comment: I just added the answer and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of your code and it will works fine:

```
const fs = require('fs')
let folder = '../../importedFiles/data';
let files_to_read = []
let files = fs.readdirSync(folder);
let fileSchema = require('../db/models/fileUpload');
let files_to_simulate = [];

files.forEach(file => {
    let fileStat = fs.statSync(folder + '/' + file).isDirectory();
    if(!fileStat) {
        files_to_read.push(file);
    }
});

fileSchema.find({}, async function(err, files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        files_to_read.forEach(function(directoryFile) {
            var dbFile = file.name.split('.');
            let dirFile = directoryFile.split('.');
            if (dbFile[0] === dirFile[0]) {
                console.log('saa')
                files_to_simulate.push(dirFile[0]);
            }
        })
    })
// If you want to have the result you need to call a function here
console.log(files_to_simulate)
});
```

If you want to export you need this:

```
const fs = require('fs')
let folder = '../../importedFiles/data';
let files = fs.readdirSync(folder);
let fileSchema = require('../db/models/fileUpload');
// in the destination file just give it a callback
module.exports = function(callback){
let files_to_read = []
let files_to_simulate = [];

files.forEach(file => {
    let fileStat = fs.statSync(folder + '/' + file).isDirectory();
    if(!fileStat) {
        files_to_read.push(file);
    }
});

fileSchema.find({}, async function(err, files) {
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        files_to_read.forEach(function(directoryFile) {
            var dbFile = file.name.split('.');
            let dirFile = directoryFile.split('.');
            if (dbFile[0] === dirFile[0]) {
                console.log('saa')
                files_to_simulate.push(dirFile[0]);
            }
        })
    })
// If you want to have the result you need to call a function here
callback(files_to_simulate)
});
}
```

Here you can read about [Asynchronous in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)

Comment: Yes, this console logs the output required. But to store the result in the files_to_simulate array what do I have to do?.  Because I will be exporting the files_to_simulate array to another file for simulating purpose 

example


module.exports = {
    files: files_to_simulate
}

Comment: It's a different problem. You need to wrapp your code in a function and return the result and export that function

Comment: My main intension is to store the result in the array rather than console logging the output.! Can you help with it

Comment: you need to wrap your code in a function and export that function

Comment: I did that but its returning promise<pending>

Comment: let temp  = async function() {
    await fileSchema.find({}, function(err, files) {
        for ( let file of files) {
            for ( let directoryFile of files_to_read) {
                var dbFile = file.name.split('.');
                let dirFile = directoryFile.split('.');
                if (dbFile[0] === dirFile[0]) {
                    files_to_simulate.push(dirFile[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return files_to_simulate;
}

let tempa = temp().then(console.log);

console.log(tempa)

Comment: Let me know if it helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla?file=/src/index.js:0-903

Comment: The link is showing a index.js with something about parceljs. is it wrong link you sent check once.!

Comment: I add it to answer. Check it out

Comment: Great, Let me know if you need any help, just leave a comment here

Comment: instead of writing in its modules.export {} can we write it in the filesSchema.find({}) itself? 
these files where I export it those files shouldn't be changed since that file is used by other files. The structure shouldn't be changed

Comment: It's not possible to export it from find callback. You know the only way you can get data in nodejs from a asynchronous call is by callbacks. and if you specifically give me the flow of your data I can help you with patterns and architecture to handle the problem.

Comment: there are few files that need data in the form of the array which will run the simulation. The data file will be imported in the simulate files. the data file contains an array of format which should be like ['a','b','c'].
The data file code is the code that I posted in the question. The final output of this file should be like an array consisting of ['a','b','c'].

Comment: I don't really what you want. I mean I am not able to understand your point